# error while installing vegan in r

Tags: r, vegan

When  I tried to install vegan using `install.packages("vegan")` and using RStudio I am getting the following error message

```
* installing *source* package ‘vegan’ ...
** package ‘vegan’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong  -c cepin.f -o cepin.o
/bin/bash: gfortran: command not found
/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:157: recipe for target 'cepin.o' failed
make: *** [cepin.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘vegan’
* removing ‘/home/stephy/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/vegan’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘vegan’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpoFztoS/downloaded_packages’
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install GFortran and make sure that it is in your PATH.

You can download a binary of it for your OS from here:

https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries

Since you're on Linux after downloading it you can install it like this:

```
tar -xzvf gfortran-4.5-linux-i686.tar.gz -C /
```

Then add it to your PATH then try installing `vegan` again.

Comment: Or use your package manager, e.g. `sudo apt-get install gfortran` or something similar if you are on Ubuntu or another Debian derived distribution.

Comment: Yep good point, or `yum` or whatever. I don't know what distro they are on and didn't want to have to add extra instructions to make sure their package manager is up to date tho (`apt get update`, etc).

Comment: i dont know whether this is the plateform to say thank you. it worked.

Comment: @stephy Glad it worked! If you want to say thank you then you can just check the green check mark by the answer to mark it as the solution ;)